# Missing frame and the end-of-stream event in GStreamer's AppSrc

Tags: python, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

When shutting down a GStreamer pipeline that reads frames from an appsrc, encodes them, and writes them out to a file, I noticed that although I had pushed `N` buffers into the appsrc, the file would have only `N-1` frames about 50% of the time (the remainder of the time it was `N`).

I am using GStreamer 1.14.5 on Ubuntu and I have tried sending the EOS action signal using both:

```py
self._pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
# and
self._appsrc.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by calling the appsrc method `end_of_stream` instead of emitting the action signal. [The documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/applib/gstappsrc.html?gi-language=python) says that either of these methods should work so I suppose that there is/was a bug in GStreamer 1.14.5 that resulted in the last buffer not being pushed to the output pad before the EOS was propagated down the pipeline.

TLDR: replace `self._appsrc.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())` with `self._appsrc.end_of_stream()`.